# When calculating VIX, how to deal with the problem of asymmetry of put and call data?

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, vix

I'm trying to calculate the VIX index according to the methodology of CBOE. I am looking at commodity options. I found that at some time, like at this minute, there are 13 call options out of the money, but there're 3 or fewer put options out of the money. How to deal with such asymmetric problem? Any suggestion or hit is helpful.

Comment: @nbbo2 I understand that you mean. But is there any method to deal with such a problem? I'm tryin to calculate the VIX index of commodity options. During most time, there may not be enough option data...

Comment: I am assuming you do not want to use CBOE's [CVOL](https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/cme-group-benchmark-administration/cme-group-volatility-indexes.html#indexes)? Or is your particular commodity not included in the indices? 
You could also "simply" [use a 1m ATM IVOL](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/69805/54838) as a proxy from a vol surface, provided you have one available.

Comment: @AKdemy Thank you very much! I just saw the methodology of CVOL, it's very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I have dealt with this problem in my research, here are my findings and takeaways:

1. **Not enough options are a problem**: Jiang and Tian [(2007)](https://doi.org/10.3905/jod.2007.681813) showed that an insufficient range of strikes leads to a downward bias in the calculated MFIV. The discreteness of strikes also introduces errors if strikes are too widely dispersed.
2. **How "enough" is defined**: Jiang and Tian [(2005)](https://doi.org/10.1093/rfs/hhi027) showed that reliable MFIV estimates can be obtained if the truncation point of each tail is 3.5 standard deviations (SDs, defined as multiples of $\sigma_t \sqrt{\tau}$ with $\sigma_t$ the Black&Scholes IV and $\tau$ the time to maturity) from the at-the-money forward price $F_0$. They further show that the “discretization error”, which is induced by the spacing between adjacent strike prices, is negligible below strike-price increments of 0.35 SDs.
3. **The solution**: Jiang and Tian [(2007)](https://doi.org/10.3905/jod.2007.681813) proposed a smoothing method that fills gaps and extends the strike prices. You might be interested in my R-Package [`R.MFIV`](https://github.com/m-g-h/R.MFIV) that implements the VIX calculation, quality assessment and also the smoothing method. I explained the entire derivation and calculation in this [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/17/1/39#B31-jrfm-17-00039)

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a bit of a stretch but how about inferring the value of the puts by using the put-call parity principle?

Comment: Wouldn't put call parity just give options of the same strike? This doesn't solve the issue of lack of OTM puts.

Comment: A strike which would make a call ITM makes a put OTM. I don't know how many ITM calls exist, however.

Comment: ITM options are generally less liquid.